# Extend element with fixed position to 100% height

Tags: css

I have a vertical nav bar with `fixed` position.

How can I make it **extend** all the way down **to the bottom** of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set html and body elements too.

```
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
```